# Autocompete using phpDoc

Tags: autocomplete, doctrine, phpdoc

I heard you can use phpDoc to help IDE with autocomplete. Can someone show how to use it with Doctrine?
For example, I have a JobTable class that extends Doctrine_Table with a bunch of methods and would like to have autocompletion when i type: Doctrine::getTable('Job')-> ... Is it possible? Is there a way to do it without phpDoc?

Answer (score 0):

phpDoc comments assist autocompletion mechanism because the IDE then knows the types of the parameters.

```
/**
 * @param $foo FudgingBreakingImpl
 */
function doStuff($foo) { ... }
```

This way, the IDE knows that $foo is of type FudgingBreakingImpl, so it can autocomplete anything related to $foo, e.g. `$foo->someMet`.

Comment: But that is just another way of saying function doStuff(FudgingBreakingImpl $foo) isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

In your example need of your code extending a Doctrine class, your IDE will need to know where that Doctrine code is in order to know what that object looks like.

In Eclipse, this is a matter of having the Doctrine code locally on your machine and telling your Eclipse project's "Build Path" / "Include Path" where to find it.

Unless the IDE is capable of inspecting that Doctrine code, there's no way it *can* know things your own code is inheriting from the Doctrine class.